# What is the difference between using : and ? in Malli?

Tags: validation, clojure, schema, malli

When I try to validate for data types in Malli, what is the difference between using : and ? in Malli?

Like when I try for float, it fails for :float as invalid schema. But we are allowed to use :int and :string right? So why does it fail for :float?

And why does it work for float?

---

Here is an example :

```
(m/validate :float 788.89)
Execution error (ExceptionInfo) at malli.core/-fail! (core.cljc:138).
:malli.core/invalid-schema {:schema :float}
(m/validate float? 788.89)
=> true
```

---

How does this work?

```
(m/validate :int 788)
=> true
(m/validate int? 788)
=> true
(m/validate string? "89")
=> true
(m/validate :string "89")
=> true
(m/validate string? 89)
=> false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Malli by default does not know anything about `:float`. What's available is in `malli.core/predicate-schemas`.

If you want to use `:float`, you have to use custom registry.

Comment: Then how does :string, :int work? Edited question for reference.

Comment: `:int` is available because it is in the `malli.core/type-schemas`. You can use `:double` instead.

Comment: Oh ok. That clarifies my doubt. Thanks!